# Attribute Error in Partial function used in multiprocessing application

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to use multiprocessing.map on an iterable of iterables. I am using partial because I have other arguments that need to be input, but am getting an attribute error that the original partial function is not being recognized.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from functools import partial

def g(y, x ):
    return x[0] + x[1] + y

z = partial(g, y=1)

pool = mp.Pool(2)
print(pool.map(z, [(1, 2,), (2, 3, ), (3, 4,)]))
```

I am wondering why this is and what I am doing wrong, I have tried flipping the argument position, among other things. Thanks!

Comment: This is a problem with your partial, not the pool. It can be reproduced with `print(z((1,2)))` in the main thread, no multiprocessing needed.

Comment: thanks for the comment. It led me to trying to do a small fix  ```import multiprocessing as mp
from functools import partial

def g(y, x ):
    out_1, out_2 = [int(t) for t in x.split("/"))
    return out_1 + out_2 + y

z = partial(g, y=1)

pool = mp.Pool(2)
print(pool.map(z, ["1/2", "2/3"]))```, but now, you can run z("2/3") which works but the map still does not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [`partial` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial), *If more arguments are supplied to the call, they are appended to args*. Its subtle, but it means that you can't set leading arguments by name with `partial` and then use positional arguments. Removing multiprocessing, your problem is reproducible with

```
>>> import multiprocessing as mp
>>> from functools import partial
>>> 
>>> def g(y, x ):
...     return x[0] + x[1] + y
... 
>>> z = partial(g, y=1)
>>> 
>>> z((1,2))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: g() got multiple values for argument 'y'
```

The partial has `args=(,)` and `kwargs={"y":1}`. When called, the positional arguments are appended to `args`. In effect, the call is

```
>>> g((1,2), y=1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: g() got multiple values for argument 'y'
```

The argument you hoped would be `x` became the first positional argument `y` and you also tried to define as `y=1`. In this case you can fix the problem by setting a positional argument, not a keyword argument.

```
>>> z = partial(g, 1)
>>> z((1,2))
4
```

That works because `args=(1,)`, which is the `y` you wanted to set. On each call the positional argument is appended, becoming `x`. But it only works because you are replacing the first positional arguments. It wouldn't work in the more general case where some positional arguments are set and others are not.

Going back to the original script with multiprocessing, the solution still works. `z` is just an instance of the `functools.partial` class whose `__call__` method uses the instance's `args`, `keywords` and `func` attributes to make the call. (added code to set multiprocessing type so that windows spawn can be tested on linux)

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from functools import partial
import sys

def g(y, x ):
    return x[0] + x[1] + y

z = partial(g, 1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        # optional start method for, spawn, forkserver
        mp.set_start_method(sys.argv[1])
    pool = mp.Pool(2)
    print(pool.map(z, [(1, 2,), (2, 3, ), (3, 4,)]))
```

Output

```
[4, 6, 8]
```

Comment: Hey tdelaney, thanks for this, this has gotten me much farther than I could have on my own! There is one more outstanding problem though, so after doing some googling, this solution does not work in a parallel processing context in python because the first element of args needs to be the iterable input. Still working on how to solve this catch 22, I'll let you know if I find something

Comment: @B_N - this solution works for mp as well. Once you define the partial with positional arguments instead of keyword, the iterated parameters are appended on each call as in the no-MP example. Added a demo.

Comment: `partial` doesn't handle all cases. But its just a helper. Sometimes you have to define your own interim funciton.

Comment: hmmm yes, I am getting the same results as you in this example, for some reason my main test case is still incorrect but this has been a great help so far, thanks!